# Correcting Blender Error in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, blendergis, drawing

I have a map featuring 4 data frames with the same/similar files in each data frame: esri world imagery basemap, and various shapefiles and feature classes pulling from the network.  I reopened the mxd recently and I'm getting the following drawing error:

One or more layers failed to draw:

Blender Error. Not enough memory to draw the map. Release memory by ungrouping base map layers or decelerating raster basemap layers.
Blender Error. Not enough memory to draw the map. Release memory by ungrouping base map layers or decelerating raster basemap layers.
Blender Error. Not enough memory to draw the map. Release memory by ungrouping base map layers or decelerating raster basemap layers.
Blender Error. Not enough memory to draw the map. Release memory by ungrouping base map layers or decelerating raster basemap layers.

The map looks correct in the mxd, however when I export to a PDF, the basemap is incorrect.

How do I remedy this? I'm not sure how to release memory or decelerate basemap layers and I have nothing grouped.

Using ArcMap 10.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I just closed arcmap and reopened it. Now it works.  I have no idea what was happening.